# Dijkstra's algorithm with an 2d-array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dijkstra

For the past few days I've tried to implement this algorithm. This far I've managed to make a dynamic 2d array and insert the distances between nodes, a function to remove a path between nodes and a function that tells me if there is a path between two nodes.
Now I would like to implement a function that returns the shortest path from node A to node B. I know how dijkstras algorithm works and I've read the pseudo code on wiki without being able to write any code my self. I'm really stuck here.

I've been thinking about how the code should look like and what should happen thats why I've made that function that tells me if theres a path between two nodes. Do I need any more help functions which would make implementing of dijkstras easier?

For now I have only 3 nodes but the code I would like to write needs to work in general for n nodes.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably thinking to much.

You need 2 things. A clean graph structure you understand. A good description of the algorithm you understand.
If you have both. Just start writing some code. Helpers needed will become obvious on the way.

-- edit --
You will probably need some of the following datastructures
[`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)
[`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)
[`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)

Answer (score 2):

I found several codes for this algorithm, but maybe it is better the simplest one in order to undertand it better, so you can check the differences between yours and this one, and complete yours. It is always better to program your way.

Have a look at this one and see if it helps.

http://vinodcse.wordpress.com/2006/05/19/code-for-dijkstras-algorithm-in-c-2/

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: Code deleted, and I'm going to give hints:

1. Store graph as list of adjacency lists of each vertex. (something like this `vector < vector < pair<int,int> > > g (n);`)
2. Use some data-structure to keep track what is the vertex with minimal distance in current state. (maybe set, or priority_queue to have `O(m log(n))` complexity)
3. Each time take high_priority vertex (vertex with minimal current distance), delete it from your data_structure and update distances of adjacent to deleted one vertexes.

---

**Note:** If you want to get minimal path as well, then keep some `vector<int> previous` and each time when updating distance of vertex (say `v`) set `previous[v] = index of vertex from where you came here`. Your path is `last, prev[last], prev[prev[last]],...,first` in reversed order.

Comment: @Mihran - OP clearly tagged it as homework question. It is very bad to give away the solution. You should instead give hints as how to proceed.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
The problem is that I've never ever worked with vectors so I have no idea how to use them. Can I do it in some other way? 
Now I have a 2d int array with distances between nodes and an string array that holds the cities(nodes).
Priority queue was also mentioned, does c++ have a a "standard" container? I know only how to implement a pq with a list.

Comment: Priority queues are a very important data structure - study heaps for a simple example. However, don't bother with them for now (especially since you are trying to handle vectors for now). In Dijkstra's you need to be able to recost items inside the queue efficiently, while the "standard" heap operations (in STL algorithm packages) only handle insertion and removal. But heaps are very simple, so (as long as you use a second vector to allow fast access to nodes in the heap, and mantain it appropriately) you can make the bubble-up and bubble-down procedures yourself.

Comment: I'm really unsure how to use a vector I've tried to fix it with an array. This is what I've got, have no idea if its correct.
[link](http://pastebin.com/dX6JJ30n)
don't know why formating is so f***** up.

Comment: @ogward Can you please post your code. I'll review it and tell where is the problem.

Comment: @ogward what does you keep in your Graph class? What is this->nrOfCities? What is this->connection....? Can you please post full code of your Graph Class?